# php - How do you use PHP to call a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php

I don't mean echoing a script onto a webpage. I mean literally doing something like:

```
$jsscript = loadJS("C:/myscript.js");
$ret = callJS('myjsfunction("abcdf", "asdfasdf");', $jsscript);
```

, where `$ret` would be the result of a javascript call to `myjsfunction("abcdf", "asdfadf")` where `myjsfunction` is defined in `myscript.js`.

Is there a library for this somewhere?

Comment: That makes very little sense.  If you want a browser, use web sockets; if not, use Node.js.

Comment: To what end would you do this? PHP being server-side and JavaScript in most cases being client-side?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have a pac file for a proxy (server-side), which the server will use to access the internet. I would like to use functions from the pac file, which is written in Javascript, within the PHP code. Both the PHP and JS code would be server side.

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can´t do that, you have to link to some HTML element to do this.
See that example:

**testJS.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * Example : show result from a Javascript Function inside PHP
 *
 */
?>

<script language="javascript">

    function doSomeStuff(){

       var a = document.frmStuff.val1.value;
       var b = document.frmStuff.val2.value;
       var r = document.frmStuff.result;

       r = +a + +b;
       document.frmStuff.result.value = r;
       document.frmStuff.submit();

    }

</script>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['result'])) {
        $result = $_POST['result'];
        echo "The Result is: ".$result."<br>";
    }
?>


<form name="frmStuff" action="testJS.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Click to see the result:</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="val1" name="val1" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" id="val2" name="val2" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" id="result" name="result" value="">
    <input type="button" id="do_sth" name="do_sth" onclick="doSomeStuff();" value="Send"></>
</form>
```